# PDO Query returning bool(false) when I try querying with a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, pdo

I'm trying to make a query with a PHP variable ($key) from $_POST form data, and I used bindParam to bind the parameter to the variable.

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if (isset($value) && is_numeric($value)) {
        $sql = "SELECT productPrice FROM products WHERE productName=:productName";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':productName', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($result);
    }
```

This returns 'bool(false)' on my page, and I'm not sure why it's doing that. I made sure the $key variable accurately matches the data on the SQL table that I'm querying for.

Comment: PDO doesn't throw exceptions by default, you need to configure it explicitly. Also, make sure your PHP environment actually reports errors (e.g. try printing an undefined variable).

Comment: BTW, you validate `$value` and then search by `$key`...

Comment: Yeah, seems weird to do this in a foreach loop on $_POST.  Shouldn't you be using a specific value from the $_POST?

Comment: @Devon yeah I'm not sure of another way to do this other than using a foreach loop. I might have to find a different approach entirely, but seeing as this is the only issue I'm having, I'd prefer simply figuring this out for now

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your `$key` to `$value`

`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {`

And after this you are still using `$key` instead of `$value` in this line

`$stmt->bindParam(':productName', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Try using this,

`$stmt->bindParam(':productName', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: The way I have my form set up, $key is a form item and $value is a numeric quantity that's entered by the user. Based on what info the user enters ($value), I'm searching for $key in my SQL table. I can't think of a better way to do this so for now this is how I have it set up.

Comment: Do you mean user will enter `$value` through which you will find `$key` from database?

Comment: yes exactly. It's a simple invoice generator, where the user enters a quantity ($value) for a product ($key). Based on the quantity entered by the user, the price for that item will be adjusted accordingly, but first I have to extract the price from the SQL 'products' table via a query.

Comment: @PooranPatel does the variable `$value` contains single value or multiple values?